# What is the difference between "standard output stream" and "standard output device"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, winapi

Many articles on the internet use the "Standard Input/Output/Error Stream" term *as if* each of the term has the same meaning with the "Standard Input/Output/Error Device" term used on other articles. For example, many articles say that the Standard Output Stream is the monitor by default but can be redirected to a file, printer, or other devices.

Let's take the standard output as the example:

1. What is the difference between the standard output stream and the standard output device? If there is one, what is the relation between them?

   Quoted from the help page of [GetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

   > "The standard handles of a process may be *redirected* by a call to SetStdHandle, in which case GetStdHandle returns the redirected handle."
2. Which one is redirected actually, the standard output stream or the standard output device?
3. Does each process has its own standard streams?

Comment: The stream is what the program uses to write to the device; the device is where the stream ends up.

Comment: ***data** (water) flows in **streams** (channels) until it ends up at a **device** (container).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An output device is some logical entity to which data can be written.

An output stream is a connection to an output device.

In a process, you have a standard output stream, which is connected to your standard output device. That means writing data to your standard output stream will output it to the standard output device. Of course, you can actually change to which device the stream is bound after the process has started.

To answer your last question, the answer is yes, each process has its own standard stream. Which device this actually maps to depends on the operating system and how the process was started. As an example, any process started directly from the console in Linux or Windows has its standard output stream linked to that console by default. However, this stream can be redirected by using either ">" to refer to a hardware device or file, or by "piping", which can be used to make a series of programs redirect their standard output streams to each other.

For example:
`echo hi > example.txt` would start the program "echo" with argument "hi" and set the standard output stream to the file "example.txt".

Analogously, each process also has a standard input stream and a standard error (output) stream.

Comment: this is the best explanation on the subject I've ever read so far, there is no "affectation" here. Thank you very much. :-)